# cronjob how to delete file after gunzip

Tags: unix, cron, cron-task

Im using

`wget -r  http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz | gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz && mv GeoLiteCity.dat /home/work/wp-content/plugins/shabatkeeper/GeoLiteCity.dat`

and i want to delete the GeoLiteCity.dat.gz after it was unzipped and moved.

Comment: You wont have GeoLiteCity.dat.gz file left on your drive as you unzipped it already?

Comment: so, after its unzipped it deleted automatically?

Comment: your original gz file get exploded and gets unzipped as a part of gunzip command.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your commands in parentheses, then separate each command with a semicolon:

```
(wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz; gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz; mv GeoLiteCity.dat /home/work/wp-content/plugins/shabatkeeper/GeoLiteCity.dat; rm GeoLiteCity.dat.gz)
```